# Set icon or logo for extension in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created an extension for vscode (not yet published, only installed localy), how can I set an icon to be seen in the section of the extensions in vscode?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can set the icon in the extension's `package.json` file, which is also called "extension manifest".

The field in which you set the path to an icon is called `"icon"`. The icon file itself has to be 128x128 pixels. As noted by Philipp Kief in the comments, you should use a PNG file, [not an SVG](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_constraints-for-rendering-svg-images).

Example:

```
{
    "name": "extension-name",
    "displayName": "Extension Name",
    "description": "...",
    "icon": "images/spellIcon.png",
    "version": "0.0.1",
      ...
```

[More on VS Code's official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-manifest).

Comment: When editing `package.json` in VS Code, if `repository` doesn't point to an `https`-served repo, you'll get the warning, "An icon requires a repository with HTTPS protocol to be specified in this package.json". But, `vsce` doesn't actually care and will build a VSIX for you anyway.

Comment: zanedp's issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90900

Comment: During packaging of the extension, if we get an error like `The specified icon 'extension/images/icon.png' wasn't found in the extension`. Then, there is a chance that, the folder `images` is excluded as part of `.vscodeignore` file.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is legit. But when i added the icon in package.json. It gave me a wired error saying "HTTPS protocol is not specified". I fixed it by using the repository key in it as:

```
"icon": "assets/images/qs-icon.png",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Mubashar-javed/quick-snippets"
  },
```